# playerctl status check not working when comparing output to "Playing"

Tags: bash

I wrote the following tiny script to change the icon displayed in my polybar based on the status given by playerctl

```bash
output=$(playerctl status -p spotify)
echo $output
if [[ $output =~ "Paused" ]];
then
    polybar-msg hook spotify-play-pause 1 #  
else
    polybar-msg hook spotify-play-pause 2 # 
fi
playerctl play-pause -p spotify
```

When I run this, I never enter the if clause and am unsure why.

Comment: The semicolon at the end of the `if` line is odd. I would remove it. If it still does not work, put a `set -x` at the top of the script and show us the output you get. Also make sure that you don't have any other weird settings (such as `set -e`) in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Too bad you didn't post any (debug)output. Might be an issue with what the command is outputting? You can force output in UPPERCASE for more reliable parsing with:

```
playerctl status --format "{{ uc(status) }}"
```

But another (possible more reliable) approach is for example:

```
playerctl status -p spotify 2>&1|grep -i 'paused' > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    polybar-msg hook spotify-play-pause 1 #  
else
    polybar-msg hook spotify-play-pause 2 # 
fi
playerctl play-pause -p spotify
```